# Need a stored procedure to use rows from a temp table as ANDed criteria

Tags: sql

if I have a table that contains data like the following:

```
Search Criteria Table
=================================
Group              Name
=======            =======
Surgeon            Hannibal
Anesthesiologist   Murdock
Perfusionist       Face
Nurse              BA

Data Tables
=================================
CaseId      Patient
=========   ===========
1           Colonel Lynch
2           Roderick Decker
3           Captain Crane

CaseId     PersonnelGroup       PersonnelName
=========  ================     =============
1          Surgeon              Hannibal
1          Anesthesiologist     Tawnia Baker
2          Perfusionist         Face
2          Surgeon              Hannibal
2          Anesthesiologist     Murdock
2          Nurse                BA
3          Surgeon              Frankie Santana
3          Anesthesiologist     Murdock
3          Nurse                BA
4          Surgeon              Frankie Santana
4          Anesthesiologist     Tawnia Baker
4          Perfusionist         Amy Allen
4          Nurse                BA
5          Surgeon              Hannibal
5          Anesthesiologist     Murdock
5          Perfusionist         Face
5          Nurse                BA
```

I want write a procedure that will, based on a flag, show me cases where any of these personnel worked on the case or where all of them were worked on the case. Hopefully the data I added above reflects this but I want to return all 5 cases when the "where any" mode is set and only case 5 when the "where all" mode is set.

I know that if I join the 3 tables together I will answer the "where any" part but not sure how to do the "where all" part. Does that make sense?

Is it possible to do in a single statement? I am getting the search criteria table by passing in a list of grouped pairs that I split into a table. I have control over how the data is passed into the proc so if that needs to change it can as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
select c.caseId
from cases c 
     SearchCriteria sc left outer join
     on sc.PersonnelName = c.Name and
        sc.PersonnelGroup = c.Group
group by c.caseId
having (@flag = 'all') and (count(*) = (select COUNT(sc.PersonnelName) from SearchCriteria) or
       (@flag = 'any') and count(sc.PersonnelName) > 0
```